# Change each linear Visibility inside adapter

Tags: java, android, xamarin

i'm trying to change each linear layout visibility inside adapter exept selected.

```
  LinearLayout mylinearlayout = row.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.test);
  btn.Click += delegate
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < parent.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                if (i == position)
                {

                    mylinearlayout .GetChildAt(i).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                }
                else
                {

                    mylinearlayout .GetChildAt(i).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                }

            }
I get error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzKx7.png)

Comment: Why are you looping on `parent.ChildCount` and accessing the child of `mylinearlayout` inside the loop?

Comment: i have a hidden layout under my main layout in same row. I need only every selected to be show. CheckImage

Comment: Do you use a `Model` or `POJO` class for the `ListView`? With this very less code, I suspect that the problem is, ListView recycles the view which are not visible in screen & hence you get NullReferenceException.

Comment: I'm using custom adapter. If i will use parent instead linear, works but it makes invisible all my row which i dont need that. I need only specific linear to make invisible

Comment: How can i change Example layout visibility using dynamic Position? inside custom adapter? ss.GetChildAt(tesss).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

Comment: Could you provide more code?  Where is your button in the listview or not? How do you get the  `position`?  Please provide more information.